# Regular expression to extract case insensitive substring in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the GRANT number from the a paragraph. The grant number are usually aplhanumeric, with capital alphabets and can have `-` in between, but they would all occur without any spaces.

Following are some examples of grants:

- `W9124A-18-0001`
- `007-FY2018`
- `W81XWH18PRMRPTTDA`
- `07-544`

Now I am not even certain if a paragraph would have a grant or not, so currently I am relying on the word `grant` to be present just before the grant number.

---

**Example**:

```
This research was supported by NIH/NHLBI Grant W9124A-18-0001(PI, Michael Brown)
```

I tried to use following regex

```
(?i)grant [A-Z0-9-]*
```

but its not perfect and matches `Grant w9124A-18-0001` when it shouldn't (lowercase `w`). How can I improve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the expression:

```
(?i)(?<=Grant\s)(?-i)[A-Z0-9-]+\b
```

- `(?i)` Case insensitive.
- `(?<=Grant\s)` Positive lookbehind for `Grant` followed by whitespace.
- `[A-Z0-9-]+` Match digits, alphabetic characters and dashes `-`.
- `(?-i)` Turn off case insensitivity.
- `\b` Word boundary.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/vnqXB9/2).

Turning on the case sensitivity, instead of disabling insensitivity, with:

```
(?i)(?<=Grant\s)(?c)[A-Z0-9-]+\b
```

is [only supported by Tcl](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html).

Comment: yes, I think grant should be case insesitive, but the grant number should be case sensitive. means it would have capital characters only. if it has lower case, then its not a grant

Comment: @UnbearableLightness careful with the first suggestion, only the first letter of the word grand is case-insenstive (since I was in the process of writing it : `(?<=[gG][rR][aA][nN][tT]\s)[A-Z0-9-]+\b`). Also while `(?c)` isn't supported by Java, I believe using a second occurence of `(?i)` will turn off case-insensivity (from the Pattern javadoc : `(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)   Nothing, but turns match flags i d m s u x U on - off`)

Comment: Thank you @Aaron for the comment. That is correct. From a quick look at [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) the case sensitivity flag is not widely supported.

Comment: @Aaron Yes the assumption is that we are only matching `Grant` and `grant`, not `GRant` or `grANT`. A second `(?i)` does not disable case-insensitivity, at least when tested or regex101. If OP wants to match words such as `grANT`, I will have to modify the lookbehind as you point out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn off case insensitivity after Grant.

```
(?i)grant (?-i)[A-Z0-9-]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally speaking, you're not accounting for case.  Your regex as it stands only looks for "grant" and would fail on "Grant".  Worse, your grant identifiers also have mixed case, and your regex isn't checking *that*, either.

The simplest way to solve this would be to ensure that your regex actually supported those values.  You don't need anything too fancy here; just perform a simple matching.

```
[Gg]rant [A-Za-z0-9\-]+
```

Fancier matching - such as specific subgroup matching with respect to the hyphen-deliminated parts of the grant ID - are left as an exercise for the reader.